# Usage of Arraylist in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, arraylist

I have the following part in my `Page_Load` method:

```
 DropDownList1.Items.Add("Audi");
 DropDownList1.Items.Add("BMW");
 …
 DropDownList1.Items.Add("Ford");
 …
 DropDownList1.Items.Add("Vauxhall");
 DropDownList1.Items.Add("Volkswagen");
 …
```

Some details are that I have a web form that is part of a car sales web site, part of the required functionality is
that users be able to select the manufacturer of vehicles from a drop down list. I created an `<asp:DropDownList ... />` control.

My question is how can re-write the code above to use an `ArrayList`, that is fully populated as it is instantiated, is sorted into alphabetical order, and is then used to initialise the `DropDownList`?

Comment: Try to use List<T> here instead of ArrayList. Because ArrayList.Add(Expects an object), which involves more upcasting and downcasting, you can avoid this by using generic collection,e.g. List<string> - strongly typed array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might as well get strongly-typed while we're at it:

```
var makes = new List<string> {
    "Audi",
    "BMW",
    "Ford",
    "Vauxhall",
    "Volkswagen"
};
makes.Sort(); 

DropDownList1.DataSource = makes;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: This wasn't working for me... Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075489/how-to-populate-dropdownlist-based-on-a-datatable

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
ArrayList MyArray = new ArrayList();
MyArray.Add("Audi");
MyArray.Add("BMW");
MyArray.Add("Ford");
MyArray.Add("Vauxhall");
MyArray.Add("Volkswagen");
MyArray.Sort();
MyDropDownList.DataSource = MyArray ;
MyDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static ArrayList _listOfCars = new ArrayList { "Audi", "BMW", "Ford" };

protected override Page_Load ...
{
   DropDownList1.DataSource = _listOfCars;
   DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

This should also do what you need it to do. Syntax might not be totally correct, I didn't check it in VS.

Comment: Where is the `Sort` the OP possibly needs?

Answer (score 0):

```
var makes = new List<string> 
{
    "BMW",
    "Volkswagen",
    "Ford",
    "Vauxhall",
    "Audi",
 };

  DropDownList1.DataSource = makes.OrderBy(x => x);
  DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

You can also use 'OrderByDescending' to flip it to reverse alpha.

```
makes.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var makes = new List<string>{
  "Ford",
  "Audi",
  "BMW",
  "Vauxhall"
};

makes.Sort();

DropDownList1.DataSource = makes;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided with three option ListItemCollection, Array, IList.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //List item collection
            ListItemCollection listItemCollection = new ListItemCollection();
            listItemCollection.Add("Audi");
            listItemCollection.Add("BMW");
            listItemCollection.Add("Ford");
            listItemCollection.Add("Vauxhall");
            listItemCollection.Add("Volkswagen");
            CarDropDown.DataSource = listItemCollection;
            CarDropDown.DataBind();

            //Array
            string[] myCollect = { "Audi", "BMW", "Ford", "Vauxhall", "Volkswagen" };
            CarDropDown.DataSource = myCollect;
            CarDropDown.DataBind();

            //IList
            List<string> listCollection = new List<string>();
            listCollection.Add("Audi");
            listCollection.Add("BMW");
            listCollection.Add("Ford");
            listCollection.Add("Vauxhall");
            listCollection.Add("Volkswagen");
            CarDropDown.DataSource = listCollection.OrderBy(name => name);
            CarDropDown.DataBind();
        }
```