# How to populate dropdownlist based on a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have the following code which populates a ASP.net label with values retrieved from a SP and a CachedTable:

```
public void UpdateDropDownList()
{
    string strQuery = "";

    using (SqlConnection scCon = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand scCmd = new SqlCommand("cation", scCon))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            scCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            scCmd.Parameters.Add("@ation", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cation.SelectedItem.Value;

            sda.SelectCommand = scCmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);

            var distinctValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Specialty"))
                   .Distinct();
            Label1.Text = "All Specialties<br/>";
            Label1.Text += string.Join("<br />", distinctValues); //Displays all specialties related to the location
            var k = distinctValues.ToArray();
            strQuery = "(";
            for (int y = 0; y < k.Length; y++)
            {
                if (y == 0)
                {
                    strQuery += @"[Specialty] = '" + k[y] + "'";
                }
                else
                {
                    strQuery += @" OR [Specialty] = '" + k[y] + "'";
                }
            }
            strQuery += @") AND ([Location] = '" + Location.SelectedItem.Value + "')";
            DataTable cacheTable2 = HttpContext.Current.Cache["cachedtable"] as DataTable; //first cached table
            DataTable filteredData2 = cacheTable2.Select(strQuery).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

            var distinctValues2 = filteredData2.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Name"))
                   .Distinct();
            Label1.Text += "All Providers<br/>";
            Label1.Text += string.Join("<br />", distinctValues2); //Displays all providers related to the location

            strQuery = "([Specialty] = 'All Specialties'";
            for (int y = 0; y < k.Length; y++)
            {
                strQuery += @" OR [Specialty] = '" + k[y] + "'";
            }
            strQuery += ")";
            DataTable cacheTable3 = HttpContext.Current.Cache["cachedtable2"] as DataTable; //different cached table
            DataTable filteredData3 = cacheTable3.Select(strQuery).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();

            var distinctValues3 = filteredData3.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Topic"))
                   .Distinct();
            Label1.Text += "All Topics<br/>";
            Label1.Text += string.Join("<br />", distinctValues3); //Displays all topics related to the specialty of that location

            Session.Add("DTTableLocation", dt);
        }
    }
}
```

I have four dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Location" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Location_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="Specialty" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="Name" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="Topic" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

The above C# code is executed for the `Location_SelectedIndexChanged`.

How can I replace the following:

```
Label1.Text = "All Specialties<br/>";
Label1.Text += string.Join("<br />", distinctValues); //Displays all specialties related to the location
```

with populating the `Specialty` dropdownlist (The `DataField` and the `DataValue` is the value).

```
Label1.Text += "All Providers<br/>";
Label1.Text += string.Join("<br />", distinctValues2); //Displays all providers related to the location
```

with populating the `Name` dropdownlist (The `DataField` and the `DataValue` is the value).

```
Label1.Text += "All Topics<br/>";
Label1.Text += string.Join("<br />", distinctValues3); //Displays all topics related to the specialty of that location
```

with populating the `Topic` dropdownlist (The `DataField` and the `DataValue` is the value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Specialty.DataSource = distinctValues
Specialty.DataBind()
```

You may need to adjust the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties, but I can't tell what those should be.

Do the same for all three dropdownlists.

I would also divide this code into separate functions.  Maybe `GetSpecialties` which retrieves all the specialties from the database.  `GetProviders` which builds the query and returns the providers from the cached table.  And `GetTopics` which builds that query and returns the Topics.

That would make the main function much shorter and easier to understand.  As it is right now it is very hard to read.

```
var distinctSpecialties = GetSpecialties();
Specialty.DataSource = distinctSpecialties;
Specialty.DataBind();

var distinctProviders = GetProviders(distinctSpecialties);
Name.DataSource = distinctProviders;
Name.DataBind();

var distinctTopics = GetTopics(distinctSpecialties);
Topic.DataSource = distinctTopics;
Topic.DataBind();
```

Comment: `DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Specialty'.`

Comment: I'm not sure where you are referencing a property with the name Specialty other than when you are pulling it from the database.

Comment: Please tell me what I can provide which will help you.

Comment: The code I added to my question is the only place I am doing it.

Comment: This is the error which happens in `DataBind()`: `System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TSource>)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'`

Comment: So you just put `Specialty.DataSource = distinctValues; Specialty.DataBind();` directly under where you are initializing `distinctValues` and get that error?

Comment: Yes, I moved it around and it is the same issue :/

Comment: Try converting it to a list.  `distinctValues.ToList();`